# How to position a pseudo element higher

Tags: html, css

Very simple question: I have a pseudo element (right-pointing arrows) that I would like position higher than they currently are. I've tried changing the `line-height`, but that changes the height of the element itself.

A basic outline of my problem:

**CSS:**

```
ol
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol > li
{
    display: inline;
}

ol > li + li:before 
{
    font-size: 8px;
    content: "➤"; 
    /* Want this to be positioned higher, so that it's right between the vertical height of the list items rather than floated near the bottom */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
   <li>
       <a>List item 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>List item 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>List item 3</a>
   </li>    
</ol>
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxb5gy5j/

Comment: Have you tired setting the vertical-align property?

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` and `line-height: 0px;` to `li:before` like this:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/snja5x5e/)

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol > li {
    display: inline;
}
ol > li + li:before {
    font-size: 8px;
    content:"➤";
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li> <a>List item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a>List item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a>List item 3</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution is to use `position: relative` and `top: -2px`:

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol > li {
    display: inline;
}
ol > li + li:before {
    font-size: 8px;
    content:"➤";
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li> <a>List item 1</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a>List item 2</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a>List item 3</a>

    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a higher degree of control over where you can place your bullet, you can use absolute positioning:

1. Set `ol > li + li:before` to `position:absolute`.
2. Set its parent, `ol > li` to `position:relative`.
3. You'll also need to add some padding to `ol > li` to clear the
   bullet: `padding-left:10px;`:

HTML:

```
<ol>
   <li>
       <a>List item 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>List item 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>List item 3</a>
   </li>    
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol > li
{
    display: inline;
    position:relative; /* add relative positioning to parent */
    padding-left:10px; /* add padding to clear space for bullet */
}

ol > li + li:before 
{
    font-size: 8px;
    content: "➤"; 
    position:absolute; /* absolutely position pseudo element */
    top:.5em; /* you now have lots of control over exact position of bullet */
    left:0;
    /* Want this to be positioned higher, so that it's right between the vertical height of the list items rather than floated near the bottom */
}
```

As you can see, this requires a little bit more setup, specifically adding extra padding to the parent `<li>` element to clear space for the bullet. But it also gives you a lot more control and the ability to do something more customized. It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lecxg3mp/1/